# HIbernate two entity with same name in different package but no exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entity with in different package but i dont get any exception

```
package chapter04.mapped;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    public class Message {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        Long id;

        @Column
        String content;

        @OneToOne
        Email email;

        public Message() {
        }   
    }
```

In actual with two entity in different package i should get exception why is exception not thrown in hibernate

Comment: what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Are the both the packages in Spring's base-package ??

Comment: As i understand if there are two entity with same name is not possible. But in my case i have the mentioned class in two package but still no error

Answer (score 0):

Of course that's no problem in Java in general. You only import the used classes so there's no conflict.

But be careful, both entities could write into the same database table if you don't annotate `@TableName`. This is the only reason I could mention when Hibernate would cause an error here. However, if you only use one of them, there's no problem with this (even though that doesn't make much sense).